# git rebase -i как без конфликтов перебазировать

Tags: linux, git, git-rebase

Всем привет! Такой вопрос. Давайте только для начала предсавим

Я делаю какую-то фичу. Пока ее не заоппрувили, от этой ветки я делаю еще одну ветку чтобы продолжить работу. Например: Одна ветка называется `CreateFeature`- она является пулл-реквестом от ветки `master`; Пока не одобрили эту ветку на слияние, я перехожу на новую чтобы сделать еще что-то полезное. Тоесть, находясь на ветке `CreateFeature`, я пишу `git checkout -b NewFeature`;

Сделав какую-то работу в `NewFeature`, ветку `CreateFeature` одобрили. Значит, я перехожу на нее и делаю `git rebase -i (squash)` - леплю все коммиты в один. Потом, заливаю в master.

Значит, когда одобрят ветку `NewFeature`, мне необходимо будет сделать то же самое: перебазировать ветку на `master` и сделать **git squash**;

У меня сейчас примерно такая ситуация. Я пытаюсь слепить коммиты в один и перебазировать на мастер, но каждый этап перебазирования неконтролируемо приводит в конфликтам. Вероятно из-за того, что я прибралась `git rebase` после того, как уже сделала новую ветку.

Подскажите, есть ли варианты заставить новую ветку переписать у себя историю ветки от которой она идет так, как это сделал `git rebase` ? Что-то типа `(now on NewBranch) git pull --force OldBranch`, и потом без конфликтов сквошнуть коммиты? Это очень болезненно, коммитов огромное количество, и решать на каждом из них конфликты весьма затруднительно

Comment: самый банальный совет: не занимайтесь переписыванием истории **на постоянной основе** (ведь это вообще-то экстраординарное действие) — не делайте squash, и будет вам счастье. // другими словами, железной многотысячелетней максимой: не создавайте сами себе проблем — не придётся их впоследствии героически преодолевать.

Comment: ну а если переписывание истории — это для вас «требование свыше», а не ваше произвольное решение, то после переписывания перебазируйте и все остальные указатели на новую, изменённую основу.

Comment: Анастасия, так а в чём проблема стартовать каждую новую фичу от мастера, а не от текущей? Во-вторых, всегда можно подмержить в начало new_feature уже созданную create_feature. У вас налицо проблемы с процессом, а не с Git.

Comment: фича зависит от ветки, а не от мастера

Comment: Именно, проблема **в процессе**! Вы просто подумайте, что вы делаете неверно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как оказалось, все куда проще.

1. Если ветвимся от мастера, можно обойтись `git squash + git rebase master`
2. Если ветвимся дальше от какой-то ветки, делаем вот что

1. смотрим хеш коммта head master, копируем

2)checkout на ветку, которую хотим влить

3. делаем `git reset - - soft hash`, коммитим, мержим

Главное только чтобы конфликтов не было, поэтому до reset-а можно сделать `git pull master`

Answer (score 2):

вот в некоторый момент у нас имеется такая картина:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и нам требуется серию коммитов `m-n` соединить в один коммит (сделать «squash»), добавить этот коммит (назовём его `mn`) к указателю `master` (мы же помним, что в программе *git* «ветки» — это всего лишь плавающие указатели на коммит?), и продолжить работать с указателем `feature2`, но чтобы его «базой» был уже не коммит `n`, а новый коммит `mn`.

приступаем. переключаемся на `master`

```
$ git checkout master
```

и начинаем слияние с указателем `feature1`:

```
$ git merge --squash feature1
Squash commit -- not updating HEAD
Automatic merge went well; stopped before committing as requested
```

коммит при этом автоматически не создаётся, о чём нам пишет программа *git*. если возникли конфликты — разрешаем их обычным образом.

когда всё готово, делаем коммит:

```
$ git commit -m mn
```

выглядит в текущий момент картина так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

теперь надо «перебазировать» серию коммитов `x-y` на новую «базу». синтаксис:

```
$ git rebase --onto новая_база старая_база что_переносим
```

для нашего примера это будет выглядеть так:

```
$ git rebase --onto master feature1 feature2
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
Applying: x
Applying: y
```

получаем то, что требовалось:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

В вашей ситуации вероятно самым простым решением будет сначала перенести ветку `NewFeature` чтобы она базировалась от комита, который получили в результате squash-a в мастер. Путь такой

```
git checkout master # или как вариант id комита после merge
git checkout -b NewFeature-2
git cherry-pick CreateFeature..NewFeature
```

Теперь у вас в `NewFeature-2` изменения, который были сделаны в `NewFeature`, но уже с учетом squash.

Далее можно удалить `NewFeature` и переименовать `NewFeature-2` и далее уже хоть rebase хоть merge.

Comment: Зачем так сложно?

Comment: Видите более простой способ? Поделитесь

Comment: Откомментировал ТС выше,

Comment: Сделать все изначально по другому, это, безусловно, правильно и поможет в будущем. Но это не годится для того состояния, что есть уже сейчас.

Comment: Я с трудом перевариваю то, что написано в вопросе. Например, «пул-реквест от ветки мастер». А то, что написано у вас называется `git rebase --onto...` в одну команду вместо трёх безо всякого переименования.

Comment: Идея та же. Да, с `get rebase --onto..` можно сделать это в одну команду. Проблема только в том, что плохо запоминается ибо редко используется в обычном процессе. `checkout` и `cherry-pick` более простые концептуально и гораздо более часто используемые. Мне в три приема проще сделать (с возможностью контроля каждого шага) чем искать и вспоминать какой порядок параметров у редко используемой команды.

Comment: Странно, у меня cherry-pick на группу используется, но rebase (в разных вариантах) гораздо чаще. Видимо вы любите делать простые действия, нежели всё-в-одном.